# Is the VC compiler used in Visual Studio 2015 open-source?

Tags: .net, frameworks, roslyn

VS 2015 uses the open-source Roslyn compiler for managed languages, but it doesn't seem to use it for VC++ projects.

So i was wondering, is the VC++ compiler in VS 2015 also open-sourced like Roslyn?

Comment: Roslyn only supports C# and VB.NET.  F#, Typescript, Python, C++/CLI, C++/CX and C++ keep their own compilers.  No, the C++ compiler is not open source and there are no plans to change this.

Comment: Your comment is an answer.